# ImportError: No module named weather_Core_Engine.weather_DB_Handler

Tags: python, django, sqlite, importerror, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to build a project on python using Django on pythinanywhere.
I'm not familiar at all with Django so any hints it's more than welcome.

I created a Django app called profiles and there i created some db models. so far so good.

I'm using sqlite3 and I managed to migrate the db and to correctly start my project.

now I have modified the file models.py but while running the migration using the command:
"python ./manage.py makemigrations"
I have the following issue:

```
"$ python ./manage.py makemigrations Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    self.check()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 372, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 310, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 303, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)   File "/home/Alexio/Mico_Weather_BackTrace/Mico_Weather_BackTrace/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    from profiles import views   File "/home/Alexio/Mico_Weather_BackTrace/profiles/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from profiles.weather_Core_Engine.weather_DB_Handler import DB_handler ImportError: No module named weather_Core_Engine.weather_DB_Handler"
```

here is the file view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from profiles.weather_Core_Engine.weather_DB_Handler import DB_handler
from profiles.weather_Core_Engine.weather_Request_Handler import request_weather

import time
import datetime


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    context = locals()
    template = 'home.html'
    return render(request,template,context)


def about(request):
    DB_handler.populate_db()
    # get input
    city = 'Asti'
    days = '2017/09/01'
    #s = "01/12/2011"
    days_to_time = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(days, "%Y/%m/%d").timetuple())
    print ("Hello ale before")
    #new_val = request_weather.history(city, days)
    new_val = request_weather.historyOpen(city, days)

    print ("Hello ale After")
    print (new_val)
    cities = DB_handler.get_cities()
    context = {
        'city_name':'about_Ale',
        'city_name_db':cities,
        'title':'News'
       #'city_name':'about'+  str(cities).encode('utf-8')
       #'city_name':'about'+  cities.strip().decode('utf-8')
    }
    template = 'about.html'
    return render(request,template,context)
```

also here it the modified models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
import datetime

# Create your models here.
class profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(default='description default text')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Cities(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
    Json = models.TextField()
```

I don't understand the import issue while migrating the db.
the python code for the server works fine and there is no import issue.

if needed here is the project tree:

```
├── Mico_Weather_BackTrace
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   └── wsgi.py
├── apixu-python-master
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── apixu
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── client.py
│   │   └── tests
│   │       ├── current_tests.py
│   │       └── forecast_tests.py
│   └── setup.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── media
├── profiles
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── views.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── weather_DB_Handler.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── 0002_profile_description.py
│   │   ├── 0002_profile_description.pyc
│   │   ├── 0003_cities.py
│   │   ├── 0003_cities.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── about.html
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   └── home.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── tests.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── views.pyc
│   └── weather_Core_Engine
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   ├── weather_DB_Handler.cpython-35.pyc
│       │   └── weather_Request_Handler.cpython-35.pyc
│       ├── weather_CityRegstration_Handler.py
│       ├── weather_DB_Handler.py
│       ├── weather_Request_Handler.py
│       └── weather_Updater_Handler.py
└── static
    ├── admin
    │   ├── css
    │   │   ├── base.css
    │   │   ├── changelists.css
    │   │   ├── dashboard.css
    │   │   ├── fonts.css
    │   │   ├── forms.css
    │   │   ├── login.css
    │   │   ├── rtl.css
    │   │   └── widgets.css
    │   ├── fonts
    │   │   ├── LICENSE.txt
    │   │   ├── README.txt
    │   │   ├── Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff
    │   │   ├── Roboto-Light-webfont.woff
    │   │   └── Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff
    │   ├── img
    │   │   ├── LICENSE
    │   │   ├── README.txt
    │   │   ├── calendar-icons.svg
    │   │   ├── gis
    │   │   │   ├── move_vertex_off.svg
    │   │   │   └── move_vertex_on.svg
    │   │   ├── icon-addlink.svg
    │   │   ├── icon-alert.svg
    │   │   ├── icon-calendar.svg
    │   │   ├── icon-changelink.svg
    │   │   ├── icon-clock.svg
    │   │   ├── icon-deletelink.svg
    │   │   ├── icon-no.svg
    │   │   ├── icon-unknown-alt.svg
    │   │   ├── icon-unknown.svg
    │   │   ├── icon-yes.svg
    │   │   ├── inline-delete.svg
    │   │   ├── search.svg
    │   │   ├── selector-icons.svg
    │   │   ├── sorting-icons.svg
    │   │   ├── tooltag-add.svg
    │   │   └── tooltag-arrowright.svg
    │   └── js
    │       ├── SelectBox.js
    │       ├── SelectFilter2.js
    │       ├── actions.js
    │       ├── actions.min.js
    │       ├── admin
    │       │   ├── DateTimeShortcuts.js
    │       │   └── RelatedObjectLookups.js
    │       ├── calendar.js
    │       ├── cancel.js
    │       ├── change_form.js
    │       ├── collapse.js
    │       ├── collapse.min.js
    │       ├── core.js
    │       ├── inlines.js
    │       ├── inlines.min.js
    │       ├── jquery.init.js
    │       ├── popup_response.js
    │       ├── prepopulate.js
    │       ├── prepopulate.min.js
    │       ├── prepopulate_init.js
    │       ├── timeparse.js
    │       ├── urlify.js
    │       └── vendor
    │           ├── jquery
    │           │   ├── LICENSE-JQUERY.txt
    │           │   ├── jquery.js
    │           │   └── jquery.min.js
    │           └── xregexp
    │               ├── LICENSE-XREGEXP.txt
    │               ├── xregexp.js
    │               └── xregexp.min.js
    ├── media
    ├── static
    │   └── css
    │       ├── font-awesome.min.css
    │       ├── main.css
    │       ├── roboto.css
    │       ├── w3-theme-black.css
    │       └── w3.css
    └── static-only
        ├── admin
        │   ├── css
        │   │   ├── base.css
        │   │   ├── changelists.css
        │   │   ├── dashboard.css
        │   │   ├── fonts.css
        │   │   ├── forms.css
        │   │   ├── login.css
        │   │   ├── rtl.css
        │   │   └── widgets.css
        │   ├── fonts
        │   │   ├── LICENSE.txt
        │   │   ├── README.txt
        │   │   ├── Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff
        │   │   ├── Roboto-Light-webfont.woff
        │   │   └── Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff
        │   ├── img
        │   │   ├── LICENSE
        │   │   ├── README.txt
        │   │   ├── calendar-icons.svg
        │   │   ├── gis
        │   │   │   ├── move_vertex_off.svg
        │   │   │   └── move_vertex_on.svg
        │   │   ├── icon-addlink.svg
        │   │   ├── icon-alert.svg
        │   │   ├── icon-calendar.svg
        │   │   ├── icon-changelink.svg
        │   │   ├── icon-clock.svg
        │   │   ├── icon-deletelink.svg
        │   │   ├── icon-no.svg
        │   │   ├── icon-unknown-alt.svg
        │   │   ├── icon-unknown.svg
        │   │   ├── icon-yes.svg
        │   │   ├── inline-delete.svg
        │   │   ├── search.svg
        │   │   ├── selector-icons.svg
        │   │   ├── sorting-icons.svg
        │   │   ├── tooltag-add.svg
        │   │   └── tooltag-arrowright.svg
        │   └── js
        │       ├── SelectBox.js
        │       ├── SelectFilter2.js
        │       ├── actions.js
        │       ├── actions.min.js
        │       ├── admin
        │       │   ├── DateTimeShortcuts.js
        │       │   └── RelatedObjectLookups.js
        │       ├── calendar.js
        │       ├── cancel.js
        │       ├── change_form.js
        │       ├── collapse.js
        │       ├── collapse.min.js
        │       ├── core.js
        │       ├── inlines.js
        │       ├── inlines.min.js
        │       ├── jquery.init.js
        │       ├── popup_response.js
        │       ├── prepopulate.js
        │       ├── prepopulate.min.js
        │       ├── prepopulate_init.js
        │       ├── timeparse.js
        │       ├── urlify.js
        │       └── vendor
        │           ├── jquery
        │           │   ├── LICENSE-JQUERY.txt
        │           │   ├── jquery.js
        │           │   └── jquery.min.js
        │           └── xregexp
        │               ├── LICENSE-XREGEXP.txt
        │               ├── xregexp.js
        │               └── xregexp.min.js
        └── css
            ├── font-awesome.min.css
            ├── main.css
            ├── roboto.css
            ├── w3-theme-black.css
            └── w3.css
```

any hint?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `__init__.py` file to make `weather_Core_Engine` a module.

Answer (score 0):

at the end, I understood why my server was compiling but the DB migration was failing.

I was using the wrong Python version to launch the migration.

forcing the python version I managed to correctly migrate the DB:

```
$ python3.5 manage.py makemigrations
```

I would anyway like to thank anyone who tried to help me :)